# Finding sets in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember-data

I'm a Rails noob, but I'd like to use it as a backend for an Ember application with Ember Data. Unfortunately, I have some unknown unknowns.

The RESTAdapter documentation says:

> Comments for a post can be loaded by post.get('comments'). The REST
>   adapter will send a GET request to /comments?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3.

It will generate similar urls if you use something like App.Post.find({title: "Some Title"}), in about the format you'd expect: /posts?title=Some+Title

Is there some option, or gem I can use to handle that sort of simple query, or do I have to go parse parameters in my controllers manually?

To clarify, I'm aware that I can tell my Rails controller to return a set like:

```
@comments = Comment.find(params[:ids])
respond_with(@comments)
```

But it seems like querying on ids or accessible attributes like that would be a common enough use case for REST APIs that something would be built in, or have a gem written to handle it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful in your case:

https://github.com/ernie/ransack/

Or

https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Comment: Ransack looks very promising.  Thank you.